# Python reinitialize object

Tags: python, initialization

I have a set up where a controller (or the experiment file, which is a Python file) invokes two different Python scripts repeatedly. Let us call the controller `C`, the two scripts `A` and `B`.

`A` provides the logic and `B` is the simulator.

Each time the controller invokes `A`, I need to create a `gameObject`.

previous code for `A`:

```
# global object
gameObject = Game()   # dummy initialization to make the object "known"

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **parameters):
        # rest of the code

    def method_start(self):  # invoked at the start of each "run"
        global gameObject
        gameObject = Game()  # reinitialize the object for the current run
        # some code

    # other methods related to the logic

    def method_end(self):
        global gameObject
        del gameObject   # destroy the object at the end of this run
```

**Objective:** I now want to make `gameObject` a part of the `class A`.

So I made the following changes.

Current code for `A`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **parameters):
        self.gameObject = Game()  # no more global object
        # rest of the code

    def method_start(self):  # invoked at the start of each "run"
        self. gameObject = Game()  # reinitialize the object for the current run
        # some code

    # other methods related to the logic

    def method_end(self):
        del self.gameObject   # destroy the object at the end of this run
```

After the change above, at the end of the first "run", the `gameObject` is deleted and I end up with the following error in `method_start()`:

`AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'gameObject'`

The workaround I have for now is to make `self.gameObject = None` in `method_end()`. However, there seems to be a steady increase in the memory consumption after every run due to this change.

How to achieve my objective without a memory leak?

=== Edit 1:
Added sample code

=== Edit 2:
Deleted sample code

I realized within the setup I gave here, the issue doesn't surface!

- My actual setup has a protocol server running in between `A`, `B`, and `C` through which the communication happens.
- Both `A` and `B` are separate processes and `C` controls the communication between them!
- I will add a sample code that *actually* shows the problem.
- In the meantime, I will also try to debug if some other method is holding the reference to `gameObject` that results in memory leak (as suggested in the comments)

Comment: The code you provide can't generate this error. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: as a workaround - in the method_end method why not first delete first (on memory leakage concerns) and assign to None (to avoid missing variable, if it is really source of error)

Comment: also can you verify which line of code does the error relate to in your file? maybe it is somewhere else?

Comment: `self.gameObject = None` does not cause a memory leak. There is no need to call `del` (and `del` wouldn't help anyway). Python's garbage collector maintains a reference count, so an object which is not referenced gets deleted from memory automatically There are other things which may be wrong: some other object may be holding a reference to `self.gameObject` (that could cause a leak), or you may be detecting memory consumption incorrectly (this is not trivial). BTW it seems wrong to have `self.gameObject = Game()` both in `__init__` and in `method_start`. One of them is probably not needed.

Comment: @zvone I will try to find if some other object is holding a reference. I inferred the memory consumption may be due to this, as this was the only change in the file.